# Convert 2d array into 1d (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

The code below currently pushes a copy of #startyear into #new. I need to convert this into 1 single array, any ideas?
Forums didn't have much

```
startyear = [["a", "b", "z"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j"]]
new = []
startyear.each do |n| #.transpose here?
    puts "looping #{n}"
    new.push(n)
    #n.join is needed somewhere
    puts "#{startyear.length} is the length of startyear"
    break if startyear.length == startyear.length[4]
end
puts "your new array is : #{new}"
```

Comment: the # comments are just ideas, i'm open to any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what all forums you've seen? And why they are't working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Array#flatten:

```
startyear = [["a", "b", "z"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j"]]
flattened = startyear.flatten
# flattened is now ["a", "b", "z", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

Comment: Much simpler then what I was going for.. good practice! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) is the obvious method to use here, but as is generally the case with Ruby, there are alternatives. Here are two.

*Use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself)*

```
startyear.flat_map(&:itself)
  #=> ["a", "b", "z", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

`itself` was introduced in Ruby v2.2. For earlier versions, use:

```
startyear.flat_map { |a| a }
```

*Use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`)*

```
startyear.reduce(:+)
  #=> ["a", "b", "z", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

Comment: Useful to note that `[[[1]]].flatten != [[[1]]].flat_map(&:itself)`

Comment: @user12341234, good to point that out. `flat_map` only works here because there is a just a single level of nesting.